SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module with mui and react ts
D:\proj\Minimal_TypeScript_v5.7.0-znaiz4(1)\Minimal_TypeScript_v5.7.0\next-ts\node_modules\mui-one-time-password-input\dist\mui-one-time-password-input.es.js:1
({"Object.":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import { jsx as k } from "react/jsx-runtime";
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

  11 |
  12 | export default function RHFCode({ name, ...other }: RHFCodesProps) {


13 |   const { control } = useFormContext();
|                                  ^
14 |
15 |   return (
16 |     <Controller

  at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (D:\proj\Minimal_TypeScript_v5.7.0-znaiz4(1)../../../../Minimal_TypeScript_v5.7.0/next-ts/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1505:14)
  at Object.<anonymous> (D:\proj\Minimal_TypeScript_v5.7.0-znaiz4(1)../../../../Minimal_TypeScript_v5.7.0/next-ts/src/components/hook-form/rhf-code.tsx:13:34)   
  at Object.<anonymous> (D:\proj\Minimal_TypeScript_v5.7.0-znaiz4(1)../../../../Minimal_TypeScript_v5.7.0/next-ts/src/components/hook-form/index.ts:41:57)       
  at Object.<anonymous> (D:\proj\Minimal_TypeScript_v5.7.0-znaiz4(1)../../../../Minimal_TypeScript_v5.7.0/next-ts/src/sections/auth/sample/sample-login-view.tsx:32:59)
  at Object.<anonymous> (D:\proj\Minimal_TypeScript_v5.7.0-znaiz4(1)../../../../Minimal_TypeScript_v5.7.0/next-ts/src/sections/auth/sample/index.ts:19:65)       
  at Object.<anonymous> (D:\proj\Minimal_TypeScript_v5.7.0-znaiz4(1)../../../../Minimal_TypeScript_v5.7.0/next-ts/src/__tests__/SampleLoginUIFields.test.tsx:7:17)

While I'm running the jest test case , I'm facing this above error .how I resolve this error.
